# Could not Autowire.No Beans of UserDetailService type found

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, autowired

**Here is the error details when i run.**

> APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Field userDetailsService in com.word.security.WebSecurityConfig
> required a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService'
> that could not be found.
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
> 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' in
> your configuration.

**Here is the   `WebSecurityConfig.java`  class**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Service
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // disable caching
        http.headers().cacheControl();

        http.csrf().disable() // disable csrf for our requests.
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/login").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/createuser").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/user/1").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                // We filter the api/login requests
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTLoginFilter("/login", authenticationManager()), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                // And filter other requests to check the presence of JWT in header
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // Create a default account
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    }
     @Bean
        public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
            return super.userDetailsService();
        }

}
```

Intellj IDEA shows the `Could not Autowire` error for `userDetailsService` below;

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
```

However, on my another class named `SecurityService` ;

```
@Service
public class SecurityService {
    @Autowired
    IUserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    public User activeUser() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        String username = auth.getName();
        Optional<User> user = userService.getUserByName(username);

        if (user.isPresent()) {
            return user.get();
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void autologin(String username, String password) {
        UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, password, AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList("USER"));

        authenticationManager.authenticate(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);

        if (usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.isAuthenticated()) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
        }
    }
}
```

***UPDATE***

**UserController.Class**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {
@Autowired
private IUserService userService;

@Autowired
private SecurityService securityService;

   @RequestMapping(value = "/createuser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String createUser(@RequestBody User user, Model md) {
        if (userService.checkExistUserName(user.getUserName())) {
            md.addAttribute("LoginError", true);
            return "bu kullanici adi ile bir kullanici bulunmaktadir. Lutfen baska bir kullanici adi ile deneyiniz";
        }
        User newUser = new User();
        newUser.setUserName(user.getUserName());
        newUser.setFirstname(user.getFirstname());
        newUser.setUserMail(user.getUserMail());
        newUser.setSurname(user.getSurname());
        newUser.setUserPassword(user.getUserPassword());
        userService.saveUser(user);

        /* Automatic login after register */
        securityService.autologin(user.getUserName(), user.getUserPassword());

        return user.getId().toString();
    }
```

I'm not getting the same error as i have on `WebSecurityConfig.java`.

But now i m getting the StackoverFlow Error shown below after attempting to create an user;

> java.lang.StackOverflowError: null    at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:441)
> ~[spring-security-config-4.2.1.RELEASE.jar:4.2.1.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:442)
> ~
> its like going into the recursive loop. Dont know how to update.

Comment: Take a look on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642199/spring-boot-autowired-not-working-in-configuration-class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.html) contains this method:

```
public UserDetailsService userDetailsServiceBean() throws Exception
```

From Java Docs:

> Override this method to expose a UserDetailsService created from configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder) as a bean.

So try to override this method in `WebSecurityConfig` like this:

```
@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return super.userDetailsService();
}
```

Comment: Thanks i m no longer having the same error. But now i'm getting the stackoverflow error . Do you have any idea why its occur?

Answer (score 1):

One of the reason for this error is as you do not have implementation of this class. Create a class called CustomUserDetailsService implementing UserDetailsService and annotate it with @Component.
Refer to spring documentation for more.