# How to autowire inside a @Configuration class during JUnit tests?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot

I'm testing a module of my multi module spring boot project.

I'm unit testing a class annotated as @Configuration. There is a method that uses a class that is injected with @Autowired. During JUnit tests, I got a NullPointer because the Autowired is not working. How to make it work?

The application is working fine, my problem is only happening on JUnit tests.

I tried some annotations found in other answers

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {BasicConfiguration.class, SomeClass.class})
@TestPropertySource(locations= "classpath:applicationTest-configs-ok.properties")
public class BasicConfigurationTest {

  @Autowired
  BasicConfiguration basicConfig;
```

```
@Configuration
public class BasicConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  private SomeClass someClass ;  <--- this is not working

  @Bean
  AnotherClass someMethod(){
    return someClass.doSomething(); <--- nullpointer
  }
```

```
@Component
SomeClass {
  @Value("${test.param}"))   <--- defined in applicationTest-configs-ok.properties
  String myParam;
}
```

someClass should be injected

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot Autowired not working in Configuration class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642199/spring-boot-autowired-not-working-in-configuration-class)

Comment: @Smajl my problem is just with this JUnit test, my application is working fine

Comment: and the `basicConfig` is injected fine?

Comment: @Antoniossss yes it is

Comment: I created exactly the same files and it works. Can you share your full scenario?

Comment: @cmlonder I found the problem. The example above, as you say, works fine. In my failing test, i was calling BasicConfiguration not using the autowired bean, but istantiating it again.. my bad

Answer (score 1):

the example above is working, the problem was in the body where I was making some mistakes.

my bad.

Comment: Shall we close it?