# How do I make Autowired work inside a Configuration class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I'm trying to autowire an attribute (myService) which is tagged as a `@Service`, inside a @Configuration class, but I get a NullPointer.
If instead, I autowire `myService` in non-configuration classes, I have no issues.

Here's the @Service I'm having issues autowiring:

```
package com.myapp.resources;

@Service
class MyService {
    public List<String> getRoutingKeys() {
        List<String> routingKeys;

        //Do stuff

        return routingKeys;
    }

    public String aMethod() {

        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Here's the @Configuration class where I can't autowire the Service

```
package com.myapp.messaging;

import com.myapp.resources;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Binding;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.BindingBuilder;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.core.TopicExchange;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {
    private List<String> routingKeys = writeRoutingKeys();

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    private List<String> writeRoutingKeys() {
        boolean test = myService == null;
        System.out.println("is the service null? " + test); //output: true!!!

        return myService.getRoutingKeys(); //here I get a NullPointer
    }

    //Methods with bean declarations for RabbitMQ
 }
```

If it helps, here's my mainclass:

```
package com.myapp;

import com.myapp.resources;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;

import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        MyService myService = (MyService) appContext.getBean(MyService.class);

        boolean test = myService == null;
        System.out.println("is the service null? " + test); //output: false

        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

If it helps, here's a different class (a @RestController) where I'm able to autowire the service

```
package com.myapp.resources;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;

    @GetMapping("/endpoint")
    public String myRestMethod() {
        boolean test = myService == null;
        System.out.println("is the service null? " + test); //output: false

        return myService.aMethod();
    }
}
```

I've also tried adding the @ComponentScan in the Configuration class, but I still get a NullPointer

```
package com.myapp.messaging;

//list of imports...

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.myapp.demo")
public class RabbitConfiguration {
   @Autowired
   private MyService myService;

   //...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring boot Autowired not working in Configuration class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33642199/spring-boot-autowired-not-working-in-configuration-class)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring will only inject the dependencies after or when a bean is instantiated (Depending if constructor injection is used or not). However , you are now accessing the dependency `MyService` during the field initialisation which happens before initialising a bean .Hence , it cannot access `MyService` during field initialisation as it is not injected yet.

You can simply fix it by changing to use constructor injection and initialise `routingKeys` inside a constructor at the same time :

```
@Configuration
public class RabbitConfiguration {

    private List<String> routingKeys ;
    private MyService myService;

    @Autowired
    public RabbitConfiguration(MyService myService){
        this.myService = myService
        this.routingKeys = writeRoutingKeys();
    }

    private List<String> writeRoutingKeys() {
        return myService.getRoutingKeys(); 
    }
 }
```

Or simply :

```
@Autowired
public RabbitConfiguration(MyService myService){
    this.myService = myService
    this.routingKeys = myService.getRoutingKeys();
}
```

Comment: The example implementation in the response should show the instance members as ```private final``` rather than simply ```private```, given that they are provided by the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest injecting the service through any `@Bean` creation method that needs it:

```
@Bean
public MyBean create(MyService myService)
```

and then pass the service into the `writeRoutingKeys(MyService myService)` method to process it accordingly.

Per documentation:

> @Configuration classes are processed quite early during the
>   initialization of the context and forcing a dependency to be injected
>   this way may lead to unexpected early initialization. Whenever
>   possible, resort to parameter-based injection as in the example above.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. In my example, I have 4 classes (Application, myService, myController, RabbitConfiguration).
I need to access an instantiated variable of myService inside RabbitConfiguration.
How do I do this according to your suggestion?  

1) Where should I put the "create" method you're suggesting?  
2) What should "MyBean" be? A 5th class?

Comment: you have a comment: //Methods with bean declarations for RabbitMQ

Comment: the problem is that no bean creation method needs the service (it is used only for the writeRoutingKeys method), so autowiring the service through a method that doesn't need the service isn't semantically correct. I've managed to solve the issue with @KenChan answer, autowiring the service in the RabbitConfiguration constructor. Anyway, your answer is also a valid one, I've upvoted it. thanks!